# SQL count categorized by different amounts

Tags: sql, count, group-by

As the title suggests. I'm trying to write a query that will give me a count of all people who haven't attended something, however I then need to group them by how many times they haven't attended. Sort of like this.

```
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------|
    |    No. Of People    |     No. of times not attended     |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------|
    |          12         |                1                  |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------|
    |          34         |                2                  |
    |---------------------|-----------------------------------|
```

In this sort of format, with the 1 meaning 'didnt attend once' and the 2 meaning 'didn't attend twice' etc etc.

This is what I have for now..

```
SELECT COUNT(p.PersonID)AS 'No. of People'
      ,COUNT(e.attended) AS 'Attended'
      ,et.EpisodeTypeName
FROM Person p
     JOIN Episode e ON e.PersonID = p.PersonID
     JOIN EpisodeType et ON et.EpisodeTypeID = e.EpisodeTypeID
WHERE e.Attended = 'No'
     AND e.EpisodeDate >= '2015-04-01' AND e.EpisodeDate <= '2016-03-31'
GROUP BY e.Attended, et.EpisodeTypeName;
```

Any help with this would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a histogram-of-histograms query.  Also, I don't see that `EpisodeType` is needed, at least based on the results and query in the question.

So, a query with two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT NotAttended, COUNT(*) as NumPeople
FROM (SELECT p.PersonID, COUNT(*) as NotAttended
      FROM Person p JOIN
           Episode e
           ON e.PersonID = p.PersonID
      WHERE e.Attended = 'No' AND
            e.EpisodeDate >= '2015-04-01' AND e.EpisodeDate <= '2016-03-31'
      GROUP BY p.PersonID
     ) p
GROUP BY NotAttended;
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted.